# adding jars dynamically from build.xml ant

Tags: ant, weblogic-10.x, ant-contrib

I created a jar file with dependencies(i.e `wlclient.jar`, `wljmxclient.jar`) added to manifest file Class-Path attribute. I get error saying  "Unsupported protocol: t3", But if I place these jars in `C:\apache-ant-1.8.3\lib` folder, this executes with no errors.

I am new to ant please help.

The ant task for creating a jar file is given below.

```
<jar destfile="projectpoc.jar" basedir="bin" excludes="**/Test.class">
        <manifest>
          <attribute name="Class-Path" 
            value=" lib/mysql-connector.jar lib/log4j-1.2.14.jar lib/ojdbc6.jar lib/wlclient.jar lib/wljmxclient.jar " />
        </manifest>
</jar>
```

Comment: Where is the projectpoc.jar created , does it reside beside the lib directory . If its created in the bin directory does the bin folder have lib directory inside it ? . If the generated jar file doesn't lay beside your lib directory , can you try placing it beside the lib directory and execute it again ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend use the [manifestclasspath](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/manifestclasspath.html) ANT task. It will correctly resolve paths relative to the jar file.

See the following answer: [Ant + Class-path Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468655/ant-class-path-issue/3481539#3481539)

Comment: I used the above method to generate jar file. But still i get the same error. <target name="buildjar">
  <manifestclasspath property="mf.classpath" jarfile="validationpoc.jar">
   <classpath>
    <fileset dir="lib" includes="*.jar" />
   </classpath>
  </manifestclasspath>
  <jar destfile="validationpoc.jar" basedir="bin" excludes="**/Test.class">
   <zipfileset dir="lib" prefix="lib" />
   <zipfileset file="lib/AntTasks.properties" />
   <manifest>
    <attribute name="Class-Path" value=". ${mf.classpath}" />
   </manifest>
  </jar>
  <echo>jar built sucessfully</echo>
 </target>