# Creating executable jar using ant : How to add external library files to the executable jar

Tags: java, ant, build

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ant - how to get all files' name in a specific folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3796824/ant-how-to-get-all-files-name-in-a-specific-folder)

I created a jar file for my project using ant. My project has some external libraries. How can i add these external library files to the executable jar.
I added the Class-path attribute in Manifest with the external jars. But it doesn't works.
How can i add the external Libraries.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using Eclipse? If so you can Export the project to Executable jar and same also Ant XML script for later use.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3468655/ant-class-path-issue/3481539#3481539

Answer (score 4):

Like so:

```
<jar destfile="${jar.file}" 
    basedir="${build.dir}" 
    manifest="${manifest.file}">
    <fileset dir="${classes.dir}" includes="**/*.class" />
    <zipgroupfileset dir="${lib.dir}" includes="**/*.jar" />
</jar>
```

Maybe this can also help:

http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/

And also reading this:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/downman.html